# How to do routing in angular2?

Tags: angular

I want to navigate from login page to home page in my angular2 project.
Here is the sample code used.

login.component.ts

```js
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent}
])

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    providers: [LoginService],
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {
login() {
    //.....
    this._router.navigate(['Home']);
}
```

home.component.ts

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.component.html'
})
```

app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <login></login>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [LoginComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent }
])
export class AppComponent {}
```

But it doesn't work. How to do the routing?

Comment: did you put <base href="/"> in your html file?

Answer (score -1):

You should define route to your home. I would suggest you add also information of where to navigate if route does not match any route. In this case your RouteConfig decorator in app.component.ts should look like:

```
@RouteConfig([
   { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true   },
   { path: '/*other', name: 'Other', redirectTo: ['/Home'] }
])
```

Now you can easily navigate to your Home component from Login:

```
this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
```